# How can I encode an image into AVIF using Java?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

How can I encode an image into AVIF using Java? For someone with little proficiency in C, is it an uphill battle (and the only way) to do it with libavif via JNI?

https://github.com/AOMediaCodec/libavif

Comment: Using the mentioned library and JNI is probably the fastest way to do it. However, if you like to help out (time, money, resources), I would like to add ImageIO support for the format, within my [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) projects. It's just not something you can just hack up in an afternoon... ;-)

Comment: AVIF support in TwelveMonkeys would be cool